# Come back to vote on more answers in X hours, or use your X remaining question votes now !

Tags: support, voting

While I was trying to vote up an asnwer I recieved the following message:

> Come back to vote on more answers in X
>   hours, or use your X remaining
>   question votes now.

When does this message appear? And what does it mean exactly !

Comment: Seems self explanatory. Is there any way that you would improve it to make it clearer?

Comment: @Cody: I didn't know that allowed voting times are divided between questions and answers ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you can come back to vote on more answers in X hours, or you can vote on Y questions.

In other words, you've used up all of your votes for answers, and you still have Y votes left for questions.

Separate vote pools for questions and answers was [implemented recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers).

Comment: Are voting times divided between questions and answers ?

Comment: @Akram: No, voting times are per day. There are separate vote pools, however.

Answer (score 2):

That mean, You can only vote on questions for today.

See [Separate vote pools for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers), which is newly implemented today.

You have 30 votes + 10 question votes / day now (previously there is only 30 votes limit)

Comment: Does that mean I have a total of 40 questions and answers votes per day. 0 - 40 for questions and 0 - 30 for answers ?

Comment: @Akram, yeah kind of, see bill's answer for detail - [Separate vote pools for questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/89547#89547)