# Bug in vote count, since status update

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, activity-summary

Hi,

I was pleased to see the new votes cast item on the user status hover over thingy...  However, I think it might have broken the restriction on the number of votes that can be cast in a day.  I appear to have voted 31 times today on stackoverflow(see picture)...

There was also no warning when I was approaching the 30 limit if that's relevant...

[image: Votes today]

EDIT: After reading the link from mmyers, I still think there's a bug...

I've voted (according to the view), **31** times.  If I try to vote on an answer, I do indeed get told I can't vote.  However, it's saying:

> Come back to vote in on more answers in 2 hours, or use your remaining **8** question votes now.

From the link, the number of question votes should be 10, so a combined total would be 40, not 31+8 (39), or am I missing something?

As an aside, it would be *nice* to get some kind of warning if I use my last 'general purpose vote', even if it is on a question.

EDIT2:

Yesterday, I have a different, but related issue.  I cast 28 votes (a lot of them were probably on questions), however I couldn't cast one of my final 30 votes on an answer.  I went round the pages a couple of times to make sure it wasn't because I was on the same page...

From Profile Page:
[image: Profile Results]

From Status View
[image: Status View]

Error when casting vote:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: @mmyers: Thanks for that, apparently I need to start listenng to the pod cast.  I still think there is an issue (albeit a smaller one).

Comment: Did you open the popup *before* voting? we only load it once per page

Comment: @Nick Craver: That's a good question and I can't give you a 100% answer.  I don't think any votes were cast between the snapshot saying 31 and the message saying I only had 8 votes left.  I think I noticed I was at 30 and hadn't had a warning, cast a vote, then refreshed the page to get the snapshot.  After @mmyers comment, I then when back and tried to upvote an answer, but I think it was on the same page.  I'm about 15 votes away from the same situation, so I may be able to reproduce it tonight / close this if I can't.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I've just gone through and done some reading on Meta / used up my votes and it looks like you're right, I can't have refreshed the page between voting for an answer and trying to vote for a question. It's working as expected here. Do you want to post an answer I can accept/ update the status to non-repro?

Comment: @Nick Craver: I've changed my mind.. there's definetly something wrong on SO.. I'm showing 28 votes cast, but can't cast anymore... votes on answers today... I'll post screen grabs tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I totally revamped the way this works, I am closing this as status-completed see:

[Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256)

Comment: Seemed to work much better yesterday.  Thanks.