# Daily vote limit hit before reaching actual counts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, voting-limits, activity-summary

According to [the latest update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers), in addition to the 30 vote limit, there's an additional 10-vote limit only for questions.

I got the notification about reaching the daily vote limit, however the dropdown notification for summary shows that I've casted only 38 votes. Is this a caching issue or are the vote counts of the alert message and the summary dropdown using separate logics?
[image]

Comment: this is an odd bug, I just changed the code paths so they use the same function, I do not see why this was happening

Comment: status-probably-fixed-in-next-deploy

Comment: @waffles I suspect this might be related to downvotes? maybe not...

Comment: @waffles this seems to have been fixed, the vote counts match. Could you please post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this the other day, and hope my re-design here: [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256) did not regress it :)

Comment: regression: the vote counts are off by 1.

Comment: @Suthya ... did you reload the page?

Comment: @waffles I did, the count is still off by 1. Btw it's @Sathya :P

Comment: @waffles - works fine now, thanks.

Comment: @waffles, it's broke on SF now. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1512/daily-vote-limit-reached-at-38-votes

Comment: @waffles regression [reported](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2776/maximum-voting-bug)

Comment: @waffles This is still the case - I have cast 38 votes during the last day according to my profile, but I'm not allowed to vote anymore.