# Undeserved Vox Populi badge

Tags: bug, badges, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Daily vote limit hit before reaching actual counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90058/daily-vote-limit-hit-before-reaching-actual-counts)

Today I received my very own shiny copy of the Vox Populi badge.* However, I seem to have received it *before* I had earned it; that is, before I had actually cast all of my 40 votes for the day, as evinced by this screenshot:

[image: Vox Populi insigne praecox]

I went on to cast the other two shortly thereafter, so perhaps you now have precognitives working in the Badge Dispensary?

---

<sub>*I am already on my second celebratory bottle of the 1980 Dom Pérignon. ;)</sub>

Comment: Maybe a post which you (down)voted got deleted the same day?

Comment: That could be, but that still seems like a bug, since I think the votes are supposed to be deleted entirely (and indeed _are_ in the vote count).

Comment: To close voters: I don't really care if the question gets closed, because I'm just pointing out a bug, not looking for an answer, but note that waffles said this is "Closed-fixed" a week ago, and, as indicated by my post, it isn't.

Comment: @Josh: I just hit the same bug (opening a [new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97364/vox-populi-with-30-votes)).