# vox populi with 30 votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, voting, voting-badges

I just got my [vox populi badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1108/vox-populi?userid=600500), which says in the description that I used my 40 votes this day.
My vote counter now shows 32 votes for today, and two of them I casted after the badge - which means, I got it by voting for only 30 answers/questions (or even less).

I also used quite a number of flags, edit approvals/rejects and close votes today, maybe these are counted here, too?

[image]

This is similar to a previous bug report [Undeserved Vox Populi badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90895/undeserved-vox-populi-badge), that got closed (as a duplicate to [Daily vote limit hit before reaching actual counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90058/daily-vote-limit-hit-before-reaching-actual-counts), which got the completed tag) - but obviously the bug is still here, since I just observed it.

Comment: Now I have reached my daily limit with 37 votes.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: I don't want a *cheated* badge. No, it is not really a problem for me, but I think it is a symptom of some underlying bug in the calculation routine. Or simply the description is wrong.

Comment: @Paŭlo: Saw your comment on [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90895/undeserved-vox-populi-badge). As far as I can recall, the count of votes displayed in the dropdown and on your user page doesn't include votes on things that got deleted, whereas the "You have X votes left today." notification and the badge _do_ count those. Just FYI -- still seems like a bug to me too.

Comment: @Josh: The interesting thing is that I got the badge and could still vote afterwards. Thus it looks like even those two counters did not use the exact same measurement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There was a bug with this badge, we were not ignoring votes on deleted posts.

I went ahead and fixed the bug ...

Which means you no longer have it, sorry.

Comment: Does this mean that if someone deletes a post on which you voted you get that vote "back" for the day?

Comment: yes they do... as soon as its deleted

Comment: *Which means you no longer have it, sorry.* – no problem here, I can try again next time :-)

Comment: Now I have my badge for real (with 40 votes).