# All of a sudden my 'Vox Populi' badge is gone. Why?

Tags: support, vote-count, voting-badges

Something strange seems to have happened.

Up until yesterday I was the proud owner of the 'Vox Populi' badge. But this morning when I logged in to StackOverflow I noticed my number of badges was one less. It turned out that it was my 'Vox Populi' badge that was missing. How could this have happened? Does it have to do with questions being deleted? That would seem strange to me, since this badge should reflect my actions (marking me as an active voter) and should be independent of the actual questions/answers I voted on.

Comment: How long does the script take to detect wrongly-awarded Vox Populi badges?  I received one (legitimately, imo) on 5/25.  Now, 6 weeks later, it has disappeared.

Comment: Heh, it's been 2 months since you've noticed it disappeared... I only noticed just now that I lost mine.  :(  I know I earned it (the first day it was introduced).  Well, made up for it today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is why?

[vox populi with 30 votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97364/vox-populi-with-30-votes)

I had a bug and some people got the badge unfairly.

Comment: Ok, so what you are saying is that even though I got this badge like a month ago, I lost it because some posts were deleted since then. Is this something that also holds true for the other vote-badges? (civic duty, for example)

Comment: No, what he says is that you were not supposed to get the badge in the first place, you got it due to a bug.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Actually, I am 100% sure that I got it fairly. Although it seems kind of hard to prove at this point.

Comment: I'm sure that as moderator waffles here has access to see all your votes and can see if you really had 40 votes in one day - I just clarified what he said in the answer. This said, you can see your own votes in your profile, including downvotes - so if you find a day where you got 40, add this to your question.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: How then can I see my votes per day? And if a post was deleted, I still couldn't prove anything. Anyway, my question wasn't about proving anything in the first place, it was an actual question.

Comment: @Rewinder sorry, my mistake I thought you can see it in your profile but I was wrong - upvotes are not stored anywhere, only the total amount. Anyhow, waffles answered the question with reasonable cause - maybe you got into the mess of 30 "normal" votes and 10 "question" votes.

Comment: @Rewinder ... yes there is an edge case, I can fix to compensate historically. In particular I can ensure deleteddate is either null or at least 24 hours after the vote. This would "fix" historical granting. however its quite an edge case I am not convinced it is worth fixing. Keep in mind we do not revoke badges unless we have a serious bug, in this case there are a handful of innocents that had the badge revoked. If you insist on us fixing this, let me know.

Comment: @waffles: Don't bother. Now I have a reason to spend some rainy sunday afternoon looking for nice questions and answers on SO to get my badge back :). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Was it a delicious bug?