# How to get Vox Populi badge when you can no longer vote after 32 votes?

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

I have the converse of the problem in [Vox Populi with 30 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97364/vox-populi-with-30-votes); well, sort of.

My counter shows 32 votes for today.  But I can no longer vote on questions (or answers, but that I expected), thus being denied the chance of obtaining the Vox Populi badge, which is marginally frustrating.  Is it that my vote counter is not properly tracking what I've been doing, or some other devious problem?  Or am I just misunderstanding the requirements for Vox Populi?

---

#### It is a design decision

I found a different way of searching (not with Vox Populi) and found:

- [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

It appears to be a ... design decision.  I don't think I understand or like the design decision, but it appears to be some sort of deliberate decision.

Comment: Have any of the questions/answers you have voted on been deleted?

Comment: Just vote on questions for one day :)

Comment: I don't think any questions or answers that I voted on have been deleted...I think the problem is discussed/described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached -- apparently it is a design feature.

Comment: @Scrooge: almost...but not quite willing to do that.  I did get 'out of votes; you can vote again in 4 seconds' though.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You only get 40 votes in a day if a sufficiently high ratio of your votes are on **questions**.  If you vote on only answers, you'll run out after 30 votes.

The more questions you vote on, the more votes over 30 you'll get.

**Bottom line**: The `Vox Populi` badge requires you to vote on a lot of questions during the day you earn it.

Comment: Yup. As scrooge noted in a comment, spend a day voting only on questions, and you'll get this badge.

Comment: Bah - I didn't see that comment.  Yes, well put by him :)

Comment: This is still worthy as an answer, since it also explains. I plussied.

Comment: GG StackOverflow, GG. Capped me at 39. Well played.

Comment: Not really. The Vox Populi badge requires that you vote on a lot of questions before voting on a lot of answers.

Comment: When voting although I use my 40 votes Vox only progresses to 17 ... there must be something else going on.