# New vote messages are misleading

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting

There are two things about the new vote messages that I don't like:

1. The new way of vote messaging doesn't tell me when I am about to reach my answer vote limit. Reaching the limit comes as a complete surprise.

   The old behaviour (`You have 5 votes left today`, `you have 4 votes left....`) should be reinstated, with additional emphasis on the vote type:

   > You have 5 answer votes left today
2. The new message

   > Come back to vote on more answers in 11 hours, or use your 10 remaining question votes now

   gives the impression that if you use your 10 remaining question votes now, you will get additional answer votes, which is not the case. It should be reworded to something like

   > Come back to vote on more answers in 11 hours; you have 10 remaining question votes today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I totally changed the way this works, the additional votes you get are kind of invisible now, you can get up to 10 free question votes, but they can be cast at any point.

The 5/4/3 left messages are all as they used to be.

See: [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)

Answer (score 2):

You could also have:

> Answer votes left: 0, Question votes left: 10. Resets in 10 hours.

Answer (score 1):

As for point number one, my understanding is that you're not informed of remaining *answer* votes intentionally. The hope is that you'll use them all up and then be forced to only vote on questions if you want to continue voting. Otherwise, people would just save their last 5 votes in reserve and never use them, just in case they found something else they wanted to vote on. Informing people of their remaining vote totals too soon would defeat [one of the principal aims](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers) of remodeling the vote system.

For the second, I agree with your proposed wording. That is probably clearer than the original for someone who doesn't understand how votes are now being distributed.