# Why is the Suffrage badge awarded for using only 30 votes when you get 40?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, voting, voting-badges

Being new to the Stack Exchange family of sites, I noticed that on Stack Overflow I am given 40 votes per day, but the Suffrage badge description states that it is awarded when one has:

> "Used all 30 votes in a day"

This seems a little strange to me, as it makes it sound like you *only have* 30 in a day, whereas the real number is 40. Am I missing something here, or is this intentional?

Comment: The number of votes has just been recently increased. You still have only 30 votes for questions and answers and 10 for questions only. Regarding the badge, I don't know whether this will be adjusted or not but I assume so.

Comment: ...and this is absolutely the right place for this sort of question. Welcome.

Comment: @Felix Ah, I thought an increase might have been the cause!  @Ninefingers Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate the edit... but I think I actually had to use all 40 of mine to get the badge.  =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(paraphrasing a comment from Felix)

The message says you “used all 30 votes” because, of the 40 votes you get, you can use up to 30 of them to vote on answers.

See this answer which proposed the current behaviour:
[Separate vote pools for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers/89547#89547)

Comment: Note in the comments to the accepted answer in the link you gave that I asked a member of the team how this would affect the "Suffrage" badge. The answer I got was that "we will probably just leave suffrage as is". That's obviously subject to change, but that's the decision as of now.

Answer (score 6):

Well this is historic.

I just changed the description to: "Used 30 votes in a day".

Also, I added a brand new badge called `Vox populi` for people who figure out how to use up the maximums 40 votes a day. (Hint: if one fourth of your votes are on questions you will be able to get the new badge.)

Comment: Will this badge also be awarded retroactively, to those users that used up all 40 votes in one day in the last week when the new system was implemented?

Comment: @Jan no ... not retroactive ...

Comment: Don't you mean "if 1/4 of your votes are on questions"?

Comment: I didn't know of the `Vox populi` until I just received it, together with `suffrage`, here at meta. To be honest, I don't see the value of having to such similar badges, especially if they both are one-time badges (are they?).

Comment: They are definitely both one-time badges.  =)

Comment: @waffles: Is this recent edit (1/3 -> 1/4) really correct?

Comment: @Hendrik yeah ... it wants 10 question votes

Comment: @waffles: Thanks for the confirmation!