# Separate rep cap for questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Recently the number of votes a user can cast was [increased to 40](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90210/why-is-the-suffrage-badge-awarded-for-using-only-30-votes-when-you-get-40/90433#90433) and the [vox populi badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/147/vox-populi) was created to encourage votes on questions.

Why not take it a step further and have two reputation caps per day: one for answers, one for questions? If we're going to encourage votes on questions let's give users room for that rep that is separate from answers.

I would envision a rep cap of 100 for questions and 200 for answers to reflect the up votes for questions only being worth half that of answers. Obviously that is open to discussion.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers/89547

Answer (score 5):

> Why not take it a step further and have two reputation caps per day: one for answers, one for questions? If we're going to encourage votes on questions let's give users room for that rep that is separate from answers.

This is a *non sequitur*. The extra votes are, as you say, to encourage voting. I don't know about you, but I have never once looked to see if the person who posted something was at the rep cap before deciding how to vote.

If anything, recent changes have been [none-too-subtly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free) trying to encourage more *downvoting* of questions, in which case adding a separate rep cap for questions would be irrelevant at best and counterproductive at worst.

Comment: Note, Jeff acknowledged there is a [cost to downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free#comment230190_90341) anyway. (Thanks for the link.)