# What does the popup message obtained when upvoting an answer say?

Tags: support, voting, popups

When I upvote an answer, a message shows up saying *"You haven't voted […]."* It just fades out so fast that I am unable to get the full message.

What's that message? Why does it fade so fast?

Comment: This is a duplicate, I just can't find the question! I can tell you though that they added the popup to encourage voting on questions.

Comment: Could it be that you did not vote any questions? Isn't that one of the changes to try to improve the questions voting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Message telling me to vote on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113862/message-telling-me-to-vote-on-questions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is :

> You haven't voted on questions in a while;
> questions need votes too!

Look at the blog entry : [Vote For This Question or The Kitten Gets It](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) for more information.

Comment: Aaahh! That blog post cleared the confusion.  Thanks.

Comment: kitten? it may be been unicorn (just may be)

Answer (score 2):

It says you haven't voted much on questions.  That means you are getting close to running out of answer votes but do have some question votes left.

Here is the question that relates to the change of max question votes:

[Separate vote pools for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers)