# Message telling me to vote on questions

Tags: support, questions, voting

When voting on a couple of answers today, a message popped up saying something like

> You haven't voted on questions in a while! Questions need votes too!

- is this new?
- what triggers this?  **As of this moment, I have way more question votes than answer votes (346 to 268).**  (My stats don't say how many of my 15 votes today were on questions, though.)
- **how do I make it stop?** (besides voting on questions)

Comment: I already vote on questions, *maybe even too much since there are more answers than questions*.

Comment: @MattFenwick `Make it stop`? How many times has this happened? **Once**? nothing to cry home about.

Comment: I got the same popup. After upvoting your question, I feel better now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> - is this new?

It's been around for at least half a year. See [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/06/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/).

> - what triggers this?

From the aforementioned blog post:

> That is, if you haven’t voted on at least one question in the last 15 votes you cast — you’ll now get the **“you haven’t voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!” reminder** every time you vote until you do.

> - **how do I make it stop?** (besides voting on questions)

You just vote on a question, *period*. There is literally nothing easier or quicker to do than that, much less anything that would *help*.

If you don't think of the ponies, please, *at the very least*, think of the kittens.

[image]

Comment: definitely annoying - should be changed to nudge occasionally and/or relate the nudge-frequency to the answer/question vote proportion

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this answer when it has a picture of a pitiful kitten with a red X over it?