# "You haven't voted on questions in a while" warning disappears too fast

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, popups

I recently got a warning just after having upvoted an answer. It said something about the fact that I haven't voted on a question for a long time and that questions need votes too.

The problem is that it disappeared so fast that the first time I could not read it at all. Well, ok, to be honest I could probably read the 2-3 first words :-) but not more.

Could not this message stay a little longer on the page?

Comment: At my first time, I retracted my vote, and voted again to read the message, because I saw a relation between voting and that message.

Comment: Never seen this warning before... I guess you **should** vote more on questions :)

Comment: Dear sirs, Please nag me harder.  I mean, longer.

Comment: @Lix Probably, indeed :-)

Comment: @AdamDavis Oh yeees, oh yees, pleeease !!! :-D

Comment: What browser / version?  I don't remember having a problem with it disappearing quickly (I usually use IE9 on Win7).

Comment: @jadarnel27 - IE?? but whyyy? :(

Comment: Question title should read "warning does not disappear *fast enough*."

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113862/message-telling-me-to-vote-on-questions

Comment: Couldn't find any documentation saying for how long the "you haven’t voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too" message appears, but since it will appear **for every vote you make on answer** guess they made it auto disappear to not anger people too much. Anyway, that's not a bug as far as I can tell.

Comment: I use Firefox 10. After reading all the comments, I don't know if it should appear, not appear at all, appear sometimes, etc. but what is sure, is that if the message appears, it should be visible long enough to be read, otherwise it is quite confusing.

Comment: For me it starts to fade almost as soon as it appears, I had to un-vote and vote about 6 times before I managed to read the whole message and understand what it said...

Comment: It seems to be using a widget intended for very short messages with one word or two. With a message as long as this, the fade time is too short.

Comment: Regardless of any suggestions on how to approve the reminder, what is the point of a notification, if most users cannot read it, because it disappears too fast? Either keep and improve it (suggestions have been made) or remove it altogether.

Comment: More than 5 years later, still the same issue.

Comment: I couldn't catch the whole message cuz of its evanescence quickly! So, I only google _You haven't voted for a question for a long time_ to get the message and am redirected here :)

Answer (score 16):

I think it's odd that the notification disappears on its own at all.  The purpose of this popup is to encourage people to vote for questions (which is an important aspect of the system, and has been addressed [multiple](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions) by the SE team).

Why not just make it dismissable by the user (like many of the other div-notifications in the system)?

Proposed solution to the bug:

[image: Click to dismiss]
*Note: jQuery not necessarily included.  Some assembly required.*

Comment: What is this *jQuery* you speak of?

Comment: @Lix Blasphemy!

Comment: Please don't make me click twice for every upvote.  I know you are trying to push, er, "encourage" voting on questions, but is it so important a goal as to make it hurt?

Comment: ooh, I *have* to down vote this, and say so since I know you're man enough to take it ;) I think the warning is explicitly meant not to be so intrusive. I vote on questions a lot myself, and I occasionally get the warning.

Comment: @AdamDavis It's pretty important to the "economy" of SO, I think.  I think it should be a little painful, and it's not too tough to relieve that pain (vote on a couple questions).  I do appreciate your point though.  Hmm.

Comment: @AndrewBarber "*explicitly meant not to be so intrusive*" - if it is by-design, then that's alright.  I just think that if question-voting important, maybe the popup should be a little irksome =)  Oh, and no worries about the downvote - that's the system working! I wasn't incredibly confident this would be the most popular idea.

Comment: If it appears for every vote, the simply compromise is to include a dismiss box the first time it shows up in a given browser session, but make it auto-dismiss thereafter.

Comment: Make it appear at the top of the entire site like Wikipedia asking you to donate does :) Give the user the power to dismiss it (for like 6 months) and that way it doesn't have to disappear so fast. It's not even about voting for answers anyways, so it doesn't make much sense to make it appear as a consequence of voting on an answer. It's about your overall behavior on SE, so it should be a notification from the website itself.

Comment: The message disappears far too quick.  I thought it was telling me I was doing something wrong.    Eventually I went to a message to capture when I upvoted, then read the captured image.  Even when reading it, it didn't make full sense to me.  I thought it was telling me I wasn't voting enough on the threads (Questions/Answers).  I understand how clear the message (separation between question and answer) is to the veterans.  But it wasn't clear to me until I performed a Google search and read this thread.  Many people will have problems with the research needed to read and decipher the mesg.

Answer (score 1):

The message comes up for a few seconds - it is meant to be transient - to dismiss itself and simply be a gentle reminder.

Comment: The transient nature makes sense but I had the same problem as the poster in that it was too quick.  There wasn't enough time to actually read the entire message.

Comment: The speed at which it dismiss itself, we can almost say it's a subliminal message.