# "You haven't voted on questions in a while" - oh yes I have

Tags: discussion, popups

I just upvoted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263611/230506) and received the pop-up message:

> You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!

I voted on a question only *4 hours* prior to receiving the popup message.

I *think* the reason I got this message is because I've viewed a long thread after my last question vote and had voted on a lot of answers.

I count I've voted on *about* 12 *answers* since my last vote on a question.

I know vote *ratio* of *questions to answers* is more useful, but 4 hours since I voted on a question *and* only having voted on 12 answers is not really much.

### Suggestions

(1):
Perhaps the maths which determines if I've "not voted in a *while*" could *buy a watch*? So as well as count the number of answers I've voted since last vote on question, also include the *time* period since I last voted on a question.

Or if it already includes a time period, a tweak is needed so users are only nudged if the time period is long, and/or the ratio of votes for question to answer is low.

(2):
More importantly, my total all time votes and question to answer ratio is currently:

- Upvotes: 1,444
- Downvotes: 719
- **On Questions**: 1,389
- On Answers: 774

I have voted on questions nearly *twice* as much as I have on answers.

So ideally whatever calculations are done to see if I should be shown the message, would also look at my total stats.
My stats show someone who does not need to be reminded to vote on questions ;)

---

That said, I made this a discussion (not bug or FR) because maybe this is not worth the effort given it's just a gentle message (well, gentle barring the apostrophe!)

Perhaps it is worthwhile, and some users with similar stats as me might be annoyed, and it have detrimental effects.

Comment: I don't think that message is time-based at all. I'm pretty sure it just looks at your consecutive votes, no matter how far apart they may be spaced, time-wise.

Comment: I think your proposal is fair. If your analysis is right, the message math should be changed.

Comment: Robots don't buy watches, especially math.

Comment: The threshold is described at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113862/message-telling-me-to-vote-on-questions

Answer (score 11):

The pop-up is totally misleading and I agree with Fish Below the Ice. I upvoted about 12 answers in about 30 seconds (and removed most of them of course) and got the same exact pop-up as you did.

Now it says that you haven't voted on questions for a while. Instead of "a while" being a time-based thing, I think that the developers wanted to say something like:

> You have been only voting on answers a lot. Please remember that questions deserves votes too!

So when they say a while, they mean that you have only been voting for answers and a for a lot of answers. The popup should be edited as you said to one similar to the example I provided where users can be less confused whether it's time-based or vote counts based.

In conclusion, the pop-up will appear after about 12+ consecutive votes on answers only and probably in the same day in UTC time. When they mean "a while", they are meaning the above instead of a time-based thing.