# "You haven't voted on questions in a while" pops up but then disappears too soon to read the full popup

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the popup message obtained when upvoting an answer say?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93709/what-does-the-popup-message-obtained-when-upvoting-an-answer-say)

I logged into Stack Overflow and started reading a question. I upvoted between 1 and 3 separate answers to that same question. Then on the 2nd or 3rd upvote click (I cannot recall which it was), a popup displayed that started with "You haven't voted on questions in a while" and then perhaps then I moved the mouse a bit (or maybe I left mouse clicked) and then the popup disappeared before I could finish reading the content of the popup.

Can someone tell me what the rest of that informative message said?

The question I was on was [Why does volatile exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552/why-does-volatile-exist)

Comment: Yes, the duplicate is over a year old...