# Voting popup can't decide which message to show

Tags: bug, popups, voting-limits

I am only getting one of these two each time I vote:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, it means you voted only on answers, and a lot. What exactly is the bug here?

Comment: That I sometimes see one and sometimes see the other

Comment: Sure about that? The "haven't voted on questions" one appears to [go away faster](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93709/what-does-the-popup-message-obtained-when-upvoting-an-answer-say) so you probably miss it.

Comment: @Sha edited, the gif may make it clearer?

Comment: Yes indeed, looks like a decent bug. :-)