# Votes, voting, and voter rewards

Tags: feature-request, voting

I ran out of votes, and I have 5 hours to go before I get more votes.  This is always disappointing, especially when you find a really great post that needs voting.  So, I came up with a plan: maybe the system should calculate if you are voting right the way it calculates if you are flagging right and give people more votes.

The way this would work could be something like this: if a user upvotes a question or answer when it is at 0 or +1, then it becomes +5+ (or maybe +10+), it counts towards awarding the user a new vote.  If the user downvotes a question that is eventually closed or reaches -5- (or maybe -10-), it also counts toward a new vote for the user.  What do you all think?

Comment: Just because you're voting the same way other people are doesn't mean you're voting "correctly".  Just because you're voting in a way that is contrary to the way most other people are voting doesn't mean you're voting "incorrectly".

Comment: @Servy Just because other people agree with you on your flags doesn't mean you are flagging correctly.

Comment: When the people validating your flags are moderators, it actually *is* a pretty safe assumption.  There are also objective criteria by which one can determine if a flag is correct.  There is no possible way for anyone to ever know if someone cast a vote because they think the post wasn't useful, or if it's because they're just mad at the author.

Comment: I also would like to have more votes (+1), but I don't think this is the way to do it (-1). Perhaps it should be a function of rep? Rep can be a sign of user involvement in a site, and the more involved you are the more you can be trusted to vote as an expert in that area.

Comment: Maybe, this was just an idea.  Feel free to suggest different ways, everyone.

Comment: The premise of the idea is good. Gotta think about implementation a bit, but the premise is good.

Answer (score 11):

I share [@Shokhet's feelings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266359/shokhet):

> I also would like to have more votes (+1), but I don't think this is the way to do it (-1).

I think one way that could work is to give people an extra 5-10 votes on posts **in their tags**. So, similarly to how it's currently 30 votes + 10 free question votes, it could be 30 votes + 10 q-votes + 10 tag-votes, per tag. What do i mean by "in your tags"? Tags where you have a [bronze badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver#comment788972_240700) (see the link).

Comment: This is an idea, but it doesn't help users without bronze badges - and those are not as common on some sites as others.

Comment: @Hosch250: But on those sites where tag badges are rarer, you are also less likely to run out of votes.

Comment: @Scimonster: You might want to propose that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver/247729#247729).

Comment: I kinda like this as the base for an idea of extra privileges for unlocking the bronze tag badge. We implemented gold, we're working on something for silver, this is a pretty cool idea for bronze.

Answer (score 4):

Let's not turn voting into a complicated game.  You know how many votes you get per day.  It's a fixed number.  Spend them wisely.

Comment: I agree. Though actually, it's a tiny bit complicated already; You get 30 if you are voting only on answers, but you can get ten more if you vote on at least 10 questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: You did not fully mention (or know) [how complicated it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238680/255554): Your question-only votes have to be cast as long as you have at least six general-purpose votes left.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yeah; True. I always forget that!! (I vote on a lot of questions, too)

Answer (score 2):

Like others have [mentioned already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247722/266359), I didn't vote on your post because while I agree that more votes would be cool, I don't think this is a good way to do this.

Maybe it should be a function of reputation points, instead? Rep can be a sign of user involvement in a site, and the more involved you are the more you can be trusted to vote as an expert in that area.
Kind of like [flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

> You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.

Maybe **one bonus vote per 200 reputation**?

Answer (score 0):

I do not support this feature request because it would only serve to heighten the disparity in activity between the less popular tags and the most popular ones.

The people most likely the obtain additional votes are those who are participating in popular tags. These are tags that **already** benefit from a lot of voting activity. When they get their additional vote, chances are that they are going to spend it where they are active.

The less popular tags are where votes are sorely needed. Most answers get a +1, the acceptance mark, and sit like this for months, no matter how correct they are. It would take a long looooong time to get the votes needed to trigger the vote "refund".

Comment: On some sites, maybe; just not the ones I'm active on. It's pretty rare on most of my sites for a good answer not to get upvotes.

Comment: I did *not* say good answers do not get *any* upvotes. I said good answer in unpopular tags can sit for a long time with only 1 upvote. I'm sure this dynamic varies by site but unless otherwise specified I take proposals submitted to Meta.SE to be proposing the feature network-wide. If the proposal is only for one site, then the proposal should be made on the Meta for the specific site. If it is for a substantial subset of sites maybe Meta.SE is the place for it but the proposal has to specify it.

Comment: I apologize; I misread your answer.

Comment: It is for all sites, most of which do not get SO-level activity. What @Shokhet was saying was that on smaller sites, niche tags don't always exist in the same way, and everything gets a higher percentage of eyeballs.