# Daily vote limit bug: Limited at 39 votes with 14 votes on questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting-limits

During a particularly extensive research session earlier this week on one site I voted on 14 questions and 25 answers, and then I got the daily vote limit reached notice every time I tried to vote on another post of either type.

Via Email 201605251528510851‏ team@stackoverflow.com confirmed the voting and said that if I was in fact getting the vote limit notice the rest of that day I should post it as a bug here.  So here it is.  Feel free to contact me for further info if needed to debug!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrzlprmft has it right. The first 25 votes for the day in question were composed of 17 answer votes and 8 question votes, giving a question-vote percentage of 32. In order to get the full 10 "bonus votes", you'd need at least 33.4%, so instead you only got 9 additional votes, putting you at a cap of 39 for the day.

Yes, this is confusing.

Comment: It matters how many question votes you cast when you cast your 25th total vote? I thought the critical point was the 25th answer vote. Also, why bring percentages into the explanation?

Comment: Fixed at your 25th vote, @wrz. PCT is easier for me because the % of 30 (default limit) determines your bonus.

Comment: Forgive my skepticism, but you are saying that things are even more complicated than [described by Waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/255554) and stuff is set in stone **before** any warning is shown? Because you should not get any warning after casting your 25th vote, as long as at least one of those votes was cast on a question.

Comment: The ratio is set at the earliest point you can be warned at, @Wrzlprmft - which is what waffles stated. Since warnings start at 5 votes remaining, and you must have at least 30 votes, that puts the fix at 25.

Comment: Waffles said that the fix happens once you actually reach the warnings (which is when either the 25th answer vote is cast or the 35th total vote is cast). You are saying that the fix happens once you could so many votes that you could possibly see a warning just going by the number of your votes (which is when the 25th total vote is cast). While either may be true, they are not the same thing.

Comment: Where are you getting 35? That'd be the *latest* possible time to start counting down, only valid if we already know you're getting 40 votes.

Comment: Okay, it would already be fixed at the 34th vote. (If you cast 24 votes on answers and 9 votes on questions and then cast another vote on a question, it is already certain that you can cast 40 votes today, though you did not see a warning. If you vote on an answer, however, you are limited to 39 votes. All going by my understanding of Waffles’ post.) But that’s not my problem: You say, things can be fixed long before you see a warning; Waffles said otherwise.

Comment: It's possible that waffles was being a bit cagey there... Note he doesn't say the limit isn't set *until* you see the warning, although that's what you're assuming. That would actually allow you to back out a couple of votes and get a different limit though.

Comment: I have another question regarding this: If I understood you correctly, the mechanism should allow me to cast 31 answer votes as follows: If from my first 25 votes, 16 are cast on answers and 9 on questions, I get the full number of bonus votes. If I proceed to cast my remaining 15 votes on answers, I would have cast 31 answer votes? Is this correct?

Comment: Looks like that's how it'd play out, @Wrzlprmft.

Answer (score 11):

This needs not necessarily be a bug. The vote limit works [as follows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/255554):

> 1. Everyone gets a total of 30 votes.
> 2. You may get up to 10 extra question votes.
> 3. Warnings remain simple... (*5 votes remaining*, *4 votes remaining*...)
> 4. Question votes may be cast at any time during the day. However, once you reach the *N votes remaining* warnings, stuff is set in stone. A question voting spree at the end will still count down.

Thus if you cast your 25<sup>th</sup> answer vote on an answer before casting your 10<sup>th</sup> question vote, you cannot spend all 40 votes on that day.

Comment: [Shameless advertisement for the campaign to simplify this logic.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238680/255554)